# Does a swarm can be configured to auto check for newer image with the same tag?

Tags: docker, github, digital-ocean, dockerhub, docker-cloud

I'm playing around with github, travis ci (build manager), digital ocean (cloud), docker hub, docker cloud to create **continuous deployment**.

I have successfuly integrated github with travis ci and with docker hub so new image is created after every pull request to one of my branches (development).

1. Docker cloud doesn't support integration with digital ocean in swarm mode. Does it mean digital ocean doesn't support swarm or the gui of docker cloud doesn't support digital ocean integration only? (I guess the answer to this is that I can do what ever I want with my machine in digital ocean).
2. Does docker cloud provide any special feature which is not accessible the using command line from a remore machine?
3. Does swarms can be configured to check for an update if a image it use have newer image with the same tag? Or even better: **Is there any service that can notify the swarm when there is a newer image with the same tag?**

Comment: Something like watchtower maybe - https://github.com/v2tec/watchtower

Comment: @johnharris85 Cool! But it is so strange that docker does not support it.. Does any other swarm alternative support it?

Answer (score 1):

I can only help with number 3.

If you want to force the swarm to get a new image version with the same tag, you can force this by using the RepoDigest of the new image.

```
docker pull myimage:tag 
docker service update \ 
       --image $(docker inspect -f '{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' myimage:tag) \ 
       my-container --force --detach=true
```

Hacky, but it works like a charm.

Comment: Why I need to specify the container name? Maby I have multiple containers which run this image.

Comment: You have to update every container? Only downloading a new image will not upgrade the service.

Comment: Then are are saying there is no way to update the whole service in real time without shutting it down first?

Comment: in general you are running more then one replic of your service. If you configure a update interval it will shut down one by one and upgrade the images.

Comment: In your answer I need to specify a container name/id. How do I run a service as you described now?